# How can I bypass license agreement page when trying to wget a package?

Tags: linux, curl, wget

I need to download a package via command line, but the page forces you to press an accept license button to start the download. Is there a way to get around that requirement with wget or curl?

https://bintray.com/jfrog/xray/download_file?file_path=xray-centos-2.11.0.tar.gz

Comment: You need to emulate what the JavaScript for the ACCEPT button does. It looks like it sends an AJAX request, which sends back a cookie or token, and then it includes that when downloading the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the parameter "agree=true" to the URL.

```
wget "https://bintray.com/jfrog/xray/download_file?agree=true&file_path=xray-centos-2.11.0.tar.gz"
```

Comment: Good job ! How did you find this ? (+1)

Comment: Well that was easy. It worked perfect Thank you!

Comment: @GillesQuenot hover over the Accept-button to see the link it leads to. Then try and see if it's really enough to add the parameter ;-)

Comment: That was easy for you, not for us ;)

Answer (score 0):

Even finding [the real URL](https://akamai.bintray.com/78/78fb3fb9f9ea6bab3f49c26e7feba7055504ae899213bc9362eb18a7ee5c7ce7?__gda__=exp=1576712464~hmac=c5437d431bf4131fe0ec80c8ecd2dd32b2acb76d458684570ee0a4b6ac3c7a64&response-content-disposition=attachment%3Bfilename%3D%22xray-centos-2.11.0.tar.gz%22&response-content-type=application%2Foctet-stream&requestInfo=U2FsdGVkX19S7-yJE2_tc1J-0F1Tn0_AGd0nlY8Tg6AGj0_Y8eS85r5e3hBnSn2xrezetxVB6kc12BDRRZEmJIC-g_cIUI0-03ejxHf6TR-9KUdE48koujXQbduMb-iAm1Yx3C34LGFC0qFwzpPNmh-Ef3Dhbwy-7ke7AE3mZUSHvAIaC-pIzbMA5ArZ6QQD&response-X-Checksum-Sha1=aa102c5b0d18e5150df9f5ebb58bd91d74f193f5&response-X-Checksum-Sha2=78fb3fb9f9ea6bab3f49c26e7feba7055504ae899213bc9362eb18a7ee5c7ce7#64;7be4893)  to download the file on akamai, it seems complicated to generate the proper `REQUEST_URI`, because there's an EPOCH time in the `exp` parameter, and if you modify it, it will return a `403 forbidden`.

And like [Barmar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1491895/barmar) said in comments, to figure out how to request the file, you have to understand what do the javascript on the page and do it programmatically.

The simplest solution (apart if you successfully do what I explain) is to code with [nodejs](/questions/tagged/nodejs) and [[image]puppeteer](/questions/tagged/puppeteer) to mimic what a human do: click on the button, etc...